# YII2 построение запроса ActiveQuery

Tags: php, yii2, activerecord

Нужна помощь в построение запроса ActiveQuery. Я уже 3 дня ломаю голову, но видимо моих знаний не достаточно.

Есть 2 таблицы:

```
- clients (
     client_id, 
     client_title, 
     client_type
     .....)

- client_details (
    row_id, 
    detail_client_id,
    detail_type,
    detail_value,
     ....)
```

Связи:

```
 public function getClientDetails()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ClientDetail::class, ['detail_client_id' => 'client_id']);
    }

   public function getClient()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Client::class, ['client_id' => 'detail_client_id']);
    }
```

В таблице clients хранятся клиенты с различными типами (нас интересуют тип 5 и 6).
В таблице client_details хранятся характеристики этих клиентов (не ограниченное количество).

Связь между клиентами разных типов 5(юр. лица) и 6(договора) следующая.
У клиента с типом 5 (из таблици clients) есть записи (несколько) в таблице client_details где detail_type =111 а detail_value-ЭТО НОМЕР ДОГОВОРА.
У клиента с типом 6 (из таблици clients) есть одна запись в таблице client_details где detail_type =86 а detail_value-ЭТО НОМЕР ДОГОВОРА.

Как построить activerecord запрос в  ClientSearch чтобы получить все записи из таблицы clients с типом 6 (с данными некоторых характеристик из таблицы client_details) и к ним притянуть client_title из таблицы clients с типом 5.
Т.е. у меня есть список договором, мне нужно вывести его в  GridView с определенными характеристиками и названием юр. лица.

Сейчас есть такой запрос:

```
$query = LegalEntity::find()->alias('c')
    ->joinWith([
        'clientDetails cd' => static function (ActiveQuery $query) {
            $query->andOnCondition(['cd.detail_type' => DetailType::TYPE_LEGAL_ENTITY_ADDRESS]);
            $query->andOnCondition(['cd.detail_status' => Detail::STATUS_ACTIVE]);
        }
    ])
    ->andFilterWhere([
        'c.client_type' => $this->validationRange
    ]);

$this->load($params);

$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => $query,
    'pagination' => [
        'pageSize' => 50
    ]
]);
```

Так получаю все заказы с характеристиками. А название юр. лица вытягиваю отдельным методом, непосредственно в GridView. Но это не позволяет фильтровать по юр. лицу и плодит много дополнительных запросов к БД.

Вот как выглядит SQL запрос:

```
 SELECT clients.client_id,
       clients.client_title,
       clients.client_type,
       (select cd.detail_value
        from  client_details cd
        where cd.detail_type = 41
          AND cd.detail_client_id = client_id
          AND cd.detail_status = 1
       LIMIT 1
       ) AS address,
       (select cd.detail_value
        from  client_details cd
        where cd.detail_type = 9
          AND cd.detail_client_id = client_id
          AND cd.detail_status = 1
        ORDER BY cd.row_id DESC
        LIMIT 1
       ) AS fias,
       (select cd.detail_value
        from  client_details cd
        where cd.detail_type = (CASE
                                    WHEN client_type = 6
                                        THEN 6
                                    WHEN client_type = 7
                                        THEN 86
                                END)
          AND cd.detail_client_id = client_id
          AND cd.detail_status = 1
        LIMIT 1
       ) AS bgb,

       (SELECT cl.client_title
           FROM clients cl
                    JOIN client_details cd ON cd.detail_client_id = cl.client_id
           WHERE
                   cd.detail_type = 111 AND
                   cd.detail_value = bgb

       GROUP BY cl.client_title
       LIMIT 1
       ) AS name

FROM clients
LEFT JOIN client_details ON client_details.detail_client_id = clients.client_id
WHERE
        (clients.client_type = 6 OR clients.client_type = 7)
        AND
        clients.client_status = 1
GROUP BY clients.client_title
```

Comment: Непонятно. Надо структуру БД. Надо что есть в БД и надо что хочется получить. Т.е. есть две таблицы с такими полями и данными, хочу получить одну таблицу с такими столбцами и данными.

Comment: Есть 2 таблицы (расписаны в начале текста).
Хочу получить таблицу Clients с полями  
     client_id, 
     client_title, 
     client_type где client_type = 6,
      + client_title из табл Clients  где client_type = 5   AS name
По связям описанным в тексте вопроса

Comment: Я же и говорю, что непонятно. 5, 6, 11 и 86. Если лень редактировать вопрос, то наверно и ответ не так уж и нужен. Кстати, можно попробовать сначала получить данные голым sql в консоли. А тогда уже его переиначить в AR.

Comment: Есть 2 таблицы (расписаны в начале текста).
Хочу написать такой запрос для ActiveDataProvider чтобы на выходе получить таблицу Clients с полями:
client_id,
client_title,
client_type где client_type = 6 (это выполняется фильтром $this->validationRange),
+
client_title AS name из табл Clients где client_type = 5.

Comment: По связям описанным в тексте вопроса.
(
У клиента с типом 5 (из таблици clients) есть записи/строки (несколько) в таблице client_details где поле
detail_type = 111
detail_value = НОМЕР ДОГОВОРА (ключевая связь).

У клиента с типом 6 (из таблици clients) есть одна запись/строка в таблице client_details где поле
detail_type = 86
detail_value = НОМЕР ДОГОВОРА (ключевая связь).
)

Answer (score 0):

Вот какой запрос получился, может кому-то пригодится.

```
 $query = LegalEntity::find()->alias('c')
        ->select(['c.client_id', 'c.client_title', 'c.client_type',
            'address' => 'cda.detail_value',
            'fias' => 'cdf.detail_value',
            'bgb' => 'cdb.detail_value',
            'nameid' => 'cdcl.detail_client_id',
            'name' => 'cl.client_title',
        ])
        ->leftJoin(['cda' => 'client_details'],
            [
                'and',
                ['cda.detail_client_id' => new Expression('c.client_id')],
                ['cda.detail_type' => DetailType::TYPE_LEGAL_ENTITY_ADDRESS],
                ['cda.detail_status' => Detail::STATUS_ACTIVE],
            ]
        )
        ->leftJoin(['cdf' => 'client_details'],
            [
                'and',
                ['cdf.detail_client_id' => new Expression('c.client_id')],
                ['cdf.detail_type' => DetailType::TYPE_FIAS],
                ['cdf.detail_status' => Detail::STATUS_ACTIVE],
            ]
        )
        ->leftJoin(['cdb' => 'client_details'],
            [
                'and',
                ['cdb.detail_client_id' => new Expression('c.client_id')],
                ['cdb.detail_type' => new Expression('CASE WHEN c.client_type = 6 THEN 6 WHEN c.client_type = 7 THEN 86 END')],
                ['cdb.detail_status' => Detail::STATUS_ACTIVE],
            ]
        )

        ->leftJoin(['cdcl' => 'client_details'],
            [
                'and',
                ['cdcl.detail_type' => DetailType::TYPE_SUBCONTRACT],
                ['cdcl.detail_value' => new Expression('cdb.detail_value')],
                ['cdb.detail_status' => Detail::STATUS_ACTIVE],
            ]
        )
        ->leftJoin(['cl' => 'clients'],
            [
                'and',
                ['cl.client_type' =>  ClientTypeList::TYPE_LEGAL_ENTITIES],
                ['cl.client_id' => new Expression('cdcl.detail_client_id')],
                ['cl.client_status' => Detail::STATUS_ACTIVE],
            ]
        )
        ->andWhere(['c.client_status' => Detail::STATUS_ACTIVE])
        ->andFilterWhere([
            'c.client_type' => $this->validationRange
        ]);
```

где

```
 DetailType::TYPE_LEGAL_ENTITY_ADDRESS = 41
 DetailType::TYPE_FIAS = 9
 DetailType::TYPE_SUBCONTRACT = 111
 Detail::STATUS_ACTIVE = 1
 $this->validationRange = [6, 7]
```